# Load a profile of Firefox in python selenium

Tags: python, ruby, firefox, selenium, watir

In ruby I can load a certain profile of FireFox like this:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name 'MyProfile'
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
b.goto 'http://192.168.0.1'
```

How can I do that in Python? As far as I know, in Python it's not supported http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html

Answer (score 3):

In Python, you can *load a specific profile by path*:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_directory="path/to/profile")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Comment: When I create a profile by "firefox -p", how would I know its path?

Comment: @PeterT. usually, to get the profile path, you go to Help -> Troubleshooting information -> Profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the name of the profile. It'll automatically load from the default location.